# Objective reasoning beyond feelings

Tags: lending-interest-ribbis, slave-serve-eved-avadim, maseches-kiddushin

I was learning recently Tosefos in Avodah Zarah and I came to the statement from [Kidushin (20a)](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00899.html#HtmpReportNum0036_L2)

> ניזבין אינש ברתיה ולא ניזיף בריביתא. מאי טעמא? ברתיה מגרעא ונפקא, והא מוספא ואזלא
>
> A person should rather sell his daughter than borrow with interest. Why? The daughter can be bought-back and the time worked is deducted by evenly dividing the time by the 6 years she would have worked. But interest just keeps on accruing.

Isn't that bit cruel? How could Judaism allow such a thing, and in general, to sell one's daughter, isn't that horrible? I understand better than both of them will eventually become homeless, but still, how can one do such a thing to one's daughter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're not aware what is involved in the sale of a daughter.

The daughter is not *sold into slavery*. She is essentially being given up for adoption, to use a modern parallel.

The aim of the *sale*  is to have her marry the *buyer* or one of his sons.

If, by age 12, they have not gotten married, she's free and goes back home. (Though she works for a maximum of 6 years, after which she is free, even if she's not yet 12 years old.)

While *in slavery* she can't be forced to do anything demeaning. She is not treated like  other slaves, but like an employee.

She actually gets preferential treatment over the other household members: E.g.: If there aren't enough pillows for everybody, then the slave gets one before the master does.

Sources: Rambam [הלכות עבדים - פרק ראשון](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02036.html#HtmpReportNum0066_L2):

> **ז:** כָּל עֶבֶד עִבְרִי **אָסוּר לְיִשְׂרָאֵל שֶׁקָּנָהוּ לְהַעֲבִידוֹ בִּדְבָרִים בּוֹזִים** שֶׁהֵם מְיֻחָדִים לַעֲשׂוֹת הָעֲבָדִים כְּגוֹן שֶׁיּוֹלִיךְ אַחֲרָיו כֵּלָיו לְבֵית הַמֶּרְחָץ אוֹ יַחְלֹץ לוֹ מִנְעָלָיו שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ויקרא כה-לט) 'לֹא תַעֲבֹד בּוֹ עֲבֹדַת עָבֶד'. **אֵינוֹ נוֹהֵג בּוֹ אֶלָּא כְּשָׂכִיר** שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ויקרא כה-מ) 'כְּשָׂכִיר כְּתוֹשָׁב יִהְיֶה עִמָּךְ'. וּמֻתָּר לְסַפֵּר לוֹ שְׂעָרוֹ וּלְכַבֵּס לוֹ כְּסוּתוֹ וְלֶאֱפוֹת לוֹ עִסָּתוֹ. אֲבָל לֹא יַעֲשֶׂה אוֹתוֹ בַּלָּן לָרַבִּים אוֹ סַפָּר לָרַבִּים אוֹ נַחְתּוֹם לָרַבִּים. וְאִם הָיְתָה אֻמָּנוּתוֹ זֹאת קֹדֶם שֶׁיִּמָּכֵר הֲרֵי זֶה יַעֲשֶׂה.‏
>
> **ט:** כָּל עֶבֶד עִבְרִי אוֹ אָמָה הָעִבְרִיָּה **חַיָּב הָאָדוֹן לְהַשְׁווֹתָן לוֹ בְּמַאֲכָל וּבְמַשְׁקֶה בִּכְסוּת וּבְמָדוֹר** שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים טו-טז) 'כִּי טוֹב לוֹ עִמָּךְ' שֶׁלֹּא תְּהֵא אַתָּה אוֹכֵל פַּת נָקִי וְהוּא אוֹכֵל פַּת קִבָּר אַתָּה שׁוֹתֶה יַיִן יָשָׁן וְהוּא שׁוֹתֶה יַיִן חָדָשׁ אַתָּה יָשֵׁן עַל גַּבֵּי מוֹכִין וְהוּא יָשֵׁן עַל גַּבֵּי הַתֶּבֶן אַתָּה דָּר בִּכְרַךְ וְהוּא דָּר בִּכְפָר אוֹ אַתָּה דָּר בִּכְפָר וְהוּא יוֹשֵׁב בִּכְרַךְ. שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ויקרא כה-מא) 'וְיָצָא מֵעִמָּךְ'. מִכָּאן אָמְרוּ כָּ**ל הַקּוֹנֶה עֶבֶד עִבְרִי כְּקוֹנֶה אָדוֹן לְעַצְמוֹ**. וְחַיָּב **לִנְהֹג בּוֹ מִנְהַג אַחְוָה** שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ויקרא כה-מו) 'וּבְאַחֵיכֶם בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל'. וְאַף עַל פִּי כֵן צָרִיךְ הָעֶבֶד לִנְהֹג בְּעַצְמוֹ מִנְהַג עַבְדוּת בְּאוֹתָן הָעֲבוֹדוֹת שֶׁהוּא עוֹשֶׂה לוֹ:

[הלכות עבדים - פרק רביעי](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02036.html#HtmpReportNum0069_L2)

> **א:** אָמָה הָעִבְרִיָּה הִיא הַקְּטַנָּה שֶׁמְּכָרָהּ אָבִיהָ. וּמִשֶּׁתָּבִיא שְׁתֵּי שְׂעָרוֹת אַחַר שְׁתֵּים עֶשְׂרֵה שָׁנָה וְתֵעָשֶׂה נַעֲרָה אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לְמָכְרָהּ אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁעֲדַיִן יֵשׁ לוֹ רְשׁוּת בָּהּ. ‏

Comment: You write "She actually gets preferential treatment over the other household members: E.g.: If there aren't enough pillows for everybody, then the slave gets one before the master does."  <--- But you also write "The daughter is not sold into slavery". So how is the slavery quote relevant?

Comment: @barlop, I was loosely translation the Rambam who says these halachot are relevant to עֶבֶד עִבְרִי אוֹ אָמָה הָעִבְרִיָּה. So she's not a slave in the dictionary definition, but she has Halachot equivalent to slaves.

Comment: since that paragraph marked 'Tet', that last paragraph, first line and the one you give me in comment, reads , `כָּל עֶבֶד עִבְרִי אוֹ אָמָה הָעִבְרִיָּה`  reads `All hebrew slaves or hebrew daughters`, you could say she has **some** halachot the same as a **hebrew** slave. I suppose not all halachot and while hebrew slaves perhaps not or not so much gentile ones.